# Bash script to echo the first positional of each line into file with name of the second

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, grep

I have a text file that is organized as follows:

```
Group 1
asdsdsdsdf.html  jeff
xcvxcvxcvx.html  bob
vrgeiuvhif.html  sue

Group 2
iwdowijdoi.html  mary
pokpompojm.html  doug
ndkjfsjfbs.html  lisa
```

I need  a `bash` script that creates a directory named after each group. And then a text file inside named for each person in that group with their corresponding link on the first line.

I have managed to be able create the directories, the named text files, and a file with only the links. But I don't know how to echo each link into each name file or how to sort them by group.

I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish the small amount that I have.

```
#!/bin/bash

grep Group list.txt > groups
grep -v Group list.txt > links_names
while read file; do mkdir "${file}"; done < groups
while read line; do export name=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
touch "$name"; done < links_names
while read line; do export link=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "$link" >> links ; done < links_names

rm {groups,links_names,links}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^Group/{g=$0; system("mkdir \""g"\""); next} g&&$0{print $1 >g"/"$2}' file
```

- `/^Group/` if the line starts with the string `Group`...

  - `g=$0` set the variable `g` to the group name, for example `Group 1`.
  - `system(...)` call the command `mkdir` with the system function to create that directory (notice the additional quotes to deal with spaces in group names).
- `g&&$0` if the variable `g` is defined and the line is not empty...

  - `print $1 >g"/"$2` write the value in the first field `$1` (the link) to a file in the directory `g` name by the value of the second field `$2` (the name).

---

The test:

```
$ cat Group\ 2/doug
pokpompojm.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Requirements

> I need a bash script that creates a directory named after each group. And then a text file inside named for each person in that group with their corresponding link on the first line.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a b
do
    # Skip blank lines
    test -z "$a" && continue

    if [[ "$a" == "Group" ]]
    then
        # Create the group directory
        group_dir="$a $b"
        mkdir "$group_dir"
    else
        # Write the link into the named file
        echo "$a" > "$group_dir/$b"
    fi
done <list.txt
```

For the purists, this assumes a number of restrictions:

- no line in your text file begins with significant whitespace
- no link contains whitespace
- there are either precisely two words per line separated by whitespace, or that lines are empty
- that the first non-blank line is a Group header

All of these assumptions can be overcome at the expense of additional code (and complexity).

Comment: You missed a quote in the echo line. But after I added one it worked perfectly. It was also much easier for me to understand than the "awk" answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your textfile is strict, as in your group will always be called "Group" followed by a space and a word and will not have any spaces in the group name, and similarly for the names after .html, this should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

parseNdostuff(){
    case $1 in
        Group)
            shift
            mkdir $1
            cd $1
            ;;
        *.html)
            link=$1
            shift
            echo $link > $1
            ;;
        *)
            cd ..
            ;;
    esac

}

while read line
do
   parseNdostuff $line
done <  mytext.txt
```

Just do a `while read line` and your text file input at the end `< mytext.txt`, and feed it to a function i wrote.  The reason I chose to do it in a function was for simplicity of dealing with each line, plus being able to easily use case and shift.

Some details:

`$1` is the first argument of the function (the `$` variables are special, look them up)

`shift` pushes down the arguments (`$1` gets dropped, `$2` becomes `$1`, `$3` -> `$2`)

when it creates a directory it `cd` into that directory so when the statement runs again and sees the .html lines it makes the files and inputs the link all in the proper directory.

`*)` is all other cases, so if you have a blank line between groups, it will just `cd ..` and go down a directory, and you'll be back where you started your script. Note, all these cd's are relative to your script placement.